# WordPress footer and nested a tag

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on a small WordPress-powered site for a friend and am having some CSS issues with the footer. The viewport is what is being seen as 100% in the container tag (for the `height` property), rather than the body tag. Also, I'm having a strange issue with an `a` tag that is properly closed in the header being spit out in every single nested element through the rest of the site. Any insight into what could be causing that?

The site can be viewed here: [www.dontyouwantto.com](http://www.dontyouwantto.com/)

Thanks

Comment: It looks to me like your problem stems from the fact that you're using absolute positioning everywhere. That can make containing elements very difficult. I suggest using floats instead (one float for your left column, another for your sidebar). Then, your footer will do just what you want it to, without having to use silly rules like height: 100% (which are generally known to be broken / flaky).

Comment: Thank you, I have gone ahead and done that, but setting the height of the container class is still only going to 100% of the viewport, rather than 100% of it's elements (You can see this by bringing up dev tools). This is something I've run into before, and don't know what exactly is causing it. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `height: 100%` rule from your **wrap** element, and replace it with `overflow: auto;`. That should do the trick in getting the container to "contain" your floated elements.

Note that you will also need to remove the `height` and `min-height` rules for your **container** element. In general, 100% height styling tactics in CSS are broken / flaky, and not recommended.